# Qt PDF Tutorial?

Tags: c++, qt

Where can I find a Qt tutorial in PDF format. I have looked all over google but can't find one. I need to be able to read it offline as I can't always be on the internet. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're looking for a tutorial or a book, rather than QT docs have a look at this free ebook :

[C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4](http://www.qtrac.eu/marksummerfield.html)

The author has released the first edition with an open license. If you like it You can still buy the printed second edition in amazon.

Comment: Now thats what I wanted!

Answer (score 9):

There is no PDF directly from trolltech that I know of, but all of the docs are under

> Qt\200x.xx\qt\doc\html

where 200x.xx represents the version of the Qt SDK. Mine is 2009.01 for example.

You could use one of many [HTML to PDF](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&q=html2pdf&btnG=Google+Search&meta=) converters to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: A little more work than what I wanted, but oh well.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually use an html to pdf converter created with QT... http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 1):

am i too late? 
you can also use an html spider that downloads an entire website.

Answer (score 0):

The second edition is also freely available (but only in HTML format):
[C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4, second edition](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0132354160). Click the Sample Content tab to access them. The chapters are all there (but in the wrong order---however, the table of contents is listed at the bottom of the page so you can see the correct order). All the examples are available from the Downloads tab.

A more advanced book is also available (but it is not free): [Advanced Qt Programming](http://www.qtrac.eu/aqpbook.html)